# Anonymous functions - my perennial undertaker

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have used anonymous functions with Java and now with JavaScript, and I still don't understand one thing.

With JavaScript, we might have the following code:

```
doSomething('omg',function(mark){
    console.log(mark);
});

function doSomething(printthis,callback){
    console.log(printthis);
    callback();
}
```

so we pass 'omg' and an anonymous function to the doSomething function.

However, where does the parameter/argument 'mark' come from? How do we pass this anonymous function the mark parameter? I swear I have seen this done time and time again, but I don't know where the mark parameter comes from.

Where?

Comment: `(function(mark){ return function(){ console.log(mark); } })('test')` I believe this is what you mean?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Calling_functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing how passing an argument to a user defined function works:

```
function doSomething(printThis, callback, context){
  var c = context || this; // if you need to bind the context of callback
  callback.call(c, printThis); // your callback is passed printThis
}
doSomething('omg', function(mark){
  console.log(mark);
});
```

You actually define the argument which you pass to your user defined function in your function which executes the callback.

Answer (score 2):

`mark` parameter would come from the call of `callback()`; however, you specify no parameters there, so `mark` will be `undefined`. If you wrote `callback(printthis + " in callback")`, then you would have received `"omg in callback"` in console.

```js
// using document.write() so it shows up on the snippet. Don't do this at home. :)

doSomething('omg',function(mark){
    document.write("<p>" + mark + "</p>");
});

function doSomething(printthis,callback){
    document.write("<p>" + printthis + "</p>");
    callback(printthis + " in callback");
}
```

Comment: `document.write()` is a bad practice.

Comment: @PHPglue: Indeed it is. Therefore the comment at the top of the code, I don't know how much clearer it can be. It is, however, the easiest way to simulate console output in a StackOverflow snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The best method would be to use `bind`, but keep in mind that `this` will need to be set, or null.

```
doSomething('omg',function(mark){
    console.log(mark);
}.bind(null, 'test'));

function doSomething(printthis,callback){
    console.log(printthis);
    callback();
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Evilzebra/6bpjrj8u/)

This can also be achieved by wrapping in another anonymous function.

```
doSomething('omg',(function(mark){
    return function(){
        console.log(mark);
    }
})('test'));

function doSomething(printthis,callback){
    console.log(printthis);
    callback();
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Evilzebra/1y4t86r2/)

Comment: yeah that works, but I swear I have seen it without the self-invoking function style

Comment: Ohhh, yeah my bad, you can also use bind. Editing answer, one sec.